# Procedure fails but works without variables

Tags: mysql

At the moment I'm working with databses and I got a strange error wirth procedures. I have create one which gets three parameters of the type VARCHAR: `title, interpret, album`. Here is the code:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO Interpret (Name) VALUES (interpret);
    SET @idInterpret := (SELECT id FROM Interpret WHERE Name = interpret);

    INSERT IGNORE INTO Album (Name, Interpret) VALUES (album, @idInterpret);
    SET @idAlbum := (SELECT id FROM Album WHERE Name = album AND Interpret = @idInterpret);

    INSERT INTO Lied (Name, Album, Interpret) VALUES (title, @idAlbum, @idInterpret);
END
```

If I start this procedure I get an error which says that the album field can not be null (which is right) but it shouldn't be null because I read the value from the table above. If  I call exact the same lines of SQL with real data (not as procedure with varaibles) all works great. Do you have any ideas why this happens?

Comment: could you insert `@idInterpret` and `@idAlbum` into a debugging table? Or somehow print out `@idInterpret` and `@idAlbum`? Maybe the select gives no result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid naming variables and parameter as columns of your tables.

In your query:

```sql
SET @`idAlbum` := (SELECT `id`
                   FROM `Album`
                   WHERE `Name` = `album` AND `Interpret` = @`idInterpret`);
```

`Interpret`, are you referring to the parameter or column of the table?. We know that is column, MySQL interprets is the parameter.

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/463ad/1)</kbd>

See:

- [13.6.4.2 Local Variable Scope and Resolution](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/local-variable-scope.html)
- Name Conflicts within Stored Routines in [D.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)

Follow the comment @Bernd-Buffen using local varibales for this case.

Comment: You are right thank you for this answer. I thought that it is case sensitive but seems not.

Comment: @Cilenco: `Column, index, stored routine, and event names are not case sensitive on any platform, nor are column aliases.` see [9.2.2 Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html). `Parameter names are not case sensitive.` see [13.1.15 CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html).

Answer (score 0):

To use vars in a Stored Procedure you must **DECLARE** it and then you
can use them without quotes. I have changed your Query, but not tested.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE idInterpret DEFAULT ='';
    DECLARE idAlbum     DEFAULT ='';

    INSERT IGNORE INTO Interpret (Name) VALUES (interpret);
    SELECT id IN TO idInterpret FROM Interpret WHERE Name = interpret;

    INSERT IGNORE INTO Album (Name, Interpret) VALUES (album, idInterpret);
    SELECT id INTO idAlbum FROM Album WHERE Name = album AND Interpret = idInterpret;

    INSERT INTO Lied (Name, Album, Interpret) VALUES (title, idAlbum, idInterpret);
END
```